# Возможно ли вытащить картинку из прайс-листа xlsx?

Tags: java, парсер, поиск-библиотек, xlsx

Есть прайс-лист в формате xlsx, в котором в одной из колонок помещена картинка.

Можно ли вытащить картинку и сохранить ее отдельно, присвоив, к примеру, ей название — наименование позиции из этой же строчки прайс-листа.

Если да, то подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеку, которая на это способна?

Comment: Для работы с Microsoft-документами есть библиотека [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: В Excel нельзя вставить изображение в ячейку, изображение вставляется на лист. А следовательно, придётся мапить координаты изображения с ячейками.